# Rails 3: Getting started with user file uploads

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I'm creating an application that allows user generated content, including photo uploading. I have worked with file uploading in PHP applications, but since I'm new to Ruby and Rails, I was wondering if there is a common technique, plugin, or gem that makes managing file uploads really easy.

Answer (score 0):

You need the Paperclip gem.  Watch this awesome video from Ryan Bates over at RailsCasts.com then you'll be ready to rock. http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip

It's easy!